# Accessing Hive using Java JDBC Issue -Unable to read HiveServer2 uri from ZooKeeper

Tags: hive

Using Beeline i am able to connect successfully.

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxx/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNameSpace=hiveserver2
```

When i start using Java Jdbc code with same url getting following error.

**Error Logs:**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Unable to read HiveServer2 uri from ZooKeeper
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:131)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
                    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
                    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
                    at io.saagie.example.hive.HiveJdbc.main(HiveJdbc.java:23)
    Caused by: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Unable to read HiveServer2 uri from ZooKeeper
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.getNextServerUriFromZooKeeper(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:86)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.resolveAuthorityUsingZooKeeper(Utils.java:517)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.resolveAuthority(Utils.java:489)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:396)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:129)
                    ... 4 more
    Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hiveserver2
                    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
                    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
                    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1590)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203)
                    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.getNextServerUriFromZooKeeper(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:69)
                    ... 8 more
```

**Java code** :

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbc { // class name hive jdbc

    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // replace "hive” here with the name of the user the queries should run
        // as
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxx/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNameSpace=hiveserver2");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String Database = "airanalytics";
        String tableName = "airlines";
        stmt.execute("use " + Database);
        // stmt.execute("drop table if exists ” + tableName);
        // stmt.execute("create table ” + tableName + ” (key int, value
        // string)”);
        // show tables
        //String sql = "select origin from airlines where year=1988";
        //System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        //ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //while (res.next()) {
        //  System.out.println(res.getString("origin"));
        //}
    }
}
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.vk</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-read-and-write-from-hive</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hadoop.version>2.6.0</hadoop.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <hive-jdbc.version>1.2.0</hive-jdbc.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Hadoop main client artifact -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${hive-jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1000.2.4.2.10-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1000.2.4.2.10-1</version>
        </dependency>

      -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.saagie</groupId>
                <artifactId>saagie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <platformId>1</platformId>
                    <jobName>example-java-read-and-write-from-hive</jobName>
                    <jobCategory>extract</jobCategory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>io.vk.example.hive.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("ive2://xxxxxxx/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNameSpace=hiveserver2 "); Here ive2 is used instead of hive2 As start of the uri string/protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved issue ,sharing ans to help others.

We can divide my problem into two parts.

1)  I am getting following exception in Java Jdbc when tried to connect window machine while working same url on Beeline .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Unable to read HiveServer2 uri from ZooKeeper
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:131)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
                    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
                    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
                    at io.saagie.example.hive.HiveJdbc.main(HiveJdbc.java:23)
    Caused by: org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientException: Unable to read HiveServer2 uri from ZooKeeper
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.getNextServerUriFromZooKeeper(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:86)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.resolveAuthorityUsingZooKeeper(Utils.java:517)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.resolveAuthority(Utils.java:489)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:396)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:129)
                    ... 4 more
    Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hiveserver2
                    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
                    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
                    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1590)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:214)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl$3.call(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:203)
                    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:199)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:191)
                    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetChildrenBuilderImpl.forPath(GetChildrenBuilderImpl.java:38)
                    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.getNextServerUriFromZooKeeper(ZooKeeperHiveClientHelper.java:69)
                    ... 8 more
```

**Debug :**

Telnet your server to check firewall is open or blocking ports

```
Go to cmd and type telnet 

open 11.12.13.14:10000
```

In my case ports are blocked by firewall and that's reason i am getting above exception.

2) Now once ports are open ,i have tried again to run my program and start getting different error .

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170) at 
   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:266) at 

 org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37) at 
  org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:204) at 
  org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:176) at 
  org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105) at 
  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at 
  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215) at 
  com.hugedata.hive.HiveJdbcConnect.getConnection(HiveJdbcConnect.java:19) at 
  com.hugedata.hive.HiveTest.main(HiveTest.java:12)
```

After analysis found that need to match driver jar version with hive version

I was using 1.2.0 version

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Updated with 2.0.0 and it's start working.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```